# how to release memory when NavigationService is called?

Tags: windows-phone-7, memory-leaks

In my application, I noticed that when I navigate to other pages or press the back key, the memory seems to increase a huge a mount for a short period (up to 5 seconds).

For example, I use a navigate event to navigate from Page A to Page B, and then press the back key to return to Page A. Repeating this behavior for a few times, I will get the peak memory violation error.

I have tried to close and clear and stop everything possible.

How can I handle this error?

Comment: Most likely it's because you do tombstoning of your data every time you navigate.

Comment: Hi, you might wanna take a look at this post http://forums.create.msdn.com/forums/p/76007/466968.aspx :)

Comment: @ng_ducnghia voting, closing and commenting are intended to help maintain the quality and usefulness of questions for other people in the future. Having a site full vague or incomplete questions which people are ignoring degrades the value of the site and stops people being able to find useful, relevant information in the future.

Comment: @Matt: I don't care if people downvote, comment on my question, but the phrase "When are you going to learn?" doesn't have any good intend. Xin and you give me pretty good idea to check where could be the problem. You both try to be as useful as possible, I really appreciate that.

Comment: @Xin: Thanks Xin, you should post your comment as an answer!

Comment: @ng_ducnghia yes, that's not a helpful comment. An appropriate response woudl be to flag it as rude or offensive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an impossible question to answer without seeing your code as there are a near infinite number of possible causes.

As a suggestion for how to start investigating this yourself, i'd recommend using the memory profiling built in to the manog version of the SDK. (You'll need to upgraqde your project to 7.1 to use this but you could create a copy which you upgrade just to see the profiling.)

Things to look at as possible causes include:
- event handlers not being unhooked
- storyboards which are left running
- resources not disposed of
- web resources not released

Comment: Thanks Matt, I checked and I didn't close the storyboard when navigate away. After dispose the storyboard the performance have improved a lot.

Comment: @ng_ducnghia how to do close storyboard in XAML ?